# Why asp hidden field are not getting set from client side ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-3.0

I am using javascript to set asp:hiddenfield to '1' but not getting set.

I am setting it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= HdnFieldEmployeePicture.ClientID %>');
            myHidden.value = '1';
        }
    </script>
```

from:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" ClientIDMode="AutoID" UploaderStyle="Modern" runat="server"/>                                                       
<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" ID="HdnFieldHasFileUploaded" runat="server" />
```

I am checking it on server side:

```
if (HdnFieldHasFileUploaded.Value == "1")
            {
```

but not set to 1.

AsyncControl and hidden field are inside UpdatePanel.

Comment: Js uses `HdnFieldEmployeePicture`, while control has ID of `HdnFieldHasFileUploaded`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Andrei: i tried both bro, but none works

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "tried both". `HdnFieldEmployeePicture` does not make much sense, as there seems to be no such control on the page. So js should be calling `HdnFieldHasFileUploaded.ClientID`

Comment: put it as your answer and i will check it as an answer. thanks typo

Comment: I don't think it's a worthy answer. Just a typo, could happen to anyone, but is not likely to help others

Comment: Check this : http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code will not work because javascript method bindings get broken when your page is partially submitted using asp.net update panel. You need to add following lines of code to get it back to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

    // bind your methods here 

    }
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
</script>
```

Comment: ok and how to get the file name of uploaded file in javascript ?

Comment: agr apko pata ho bhai ?

Comment: @StackyFlowy use javascript FileReader to access the uploaded files